Start only deploy pipeline when tag is pushed
I have the following scipt:
stages:
  - code_build
  - code_test
  - code_deploy
  - image_build
  - nomad_deploy_dev

code_build:
  stage: code_build
  script:
    - [REDACTED]
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target/dependency-check-report.html

code_test:
  stage: code_test
  script: 
    - [REDACTED]
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml

code_deploy:
  stage: code_deploy
  script: 
    - [REDACTED]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG

image_build_dev:
  stage: image_build
  script:
        - [REDACTED]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /dev/

nomad_deploy_dev:
  stage: nomad_deploy_dev
  environment: dev
  when: on_success
  script:
        - [REDACTED]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /dev/


When I push a commit with a tag, it starts the pipeline that also deploys.
However, when i push with a tag, it also starts the regular pipeline that builds and tests.
How can I configure the script in such a way that it runs only the deploy pipeline when I push a tag and only builds & tests when i push without tag?

Your setup is almost there, you need to restrict the first two job to push scenarios only to avoid them triggering on tags:
stages:
  - code_build
  - code_test
  - code_deploy
  - image_build
  - nomad_deploy_dev

code_build:
  stage: code_build
  script:
    - [REDACTED]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target/dependency-check-report.html

code_test:
  stage: code_test
  script: 
    - [REDACTED]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml

code_deploy:
  stage: code_deploy
  script: 
    - [REDACTED]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG

image_build_dev:
  stage: image_build
  script:
        - [REDACTED]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /dev/

nomad_deploy_dev:
  stage: nomad_deploy_dev
  environment: dev
  when: on_success
  script:
        - [REDACTED]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /dev/


hm, now it runs code_deploy, image_build and nomad_deploy_dev on the actual deploy pipeline and it also runs the regular pipeline.
The deploy pipeline is missing code_build and code_test
